# Did the Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles consume alcohol?

Tags: tmnt-2-secret-of-the-ooze

In *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II*, [April is seen pouring clear liquid into Donatello's drink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7qz6.jpg). This leads to my question, did the TMNT consume alcohol? They are teens after all; however, my knowledge was that they are about 15 years old and maybe Donatello is 16. Even though the legal drinking age changed in 1985 from 18 to 21 in the US, the comics were published in 1984. Was this portion of the film improvised or part of the comic considering a "close enough to legal drinking age" perspective?

Comment: In-universe, I wonder who would be enforcing the legal drinking age on Splinter and the turtles?

Comment: @Taladris Well, it doesn't have to be enforced on Splinter and I'd suppose it would be in his responsibility to raise the Turtles to responsible young adults. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No...this is clearly a bottle of water.

[image]

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I'm not sure it's that clear that it **is** water. He is a few moments later (as Rafael says "... right into the back of a garbage truck" ) seen stirring whatever liquid is in the coffee mug. How often do people stir water? This is at April's apartment, and only those two have the liquid.

Comment: Looks like a Zima.

Comment: @Darla it *could be that they (writers/characters) are playing this for laughs, as the turtles perhaps want to look either, cool, mature or "normal" (because despite that it is illegal, teens do sometimes drink and because turtles are not human). In other words they may be pretending to drink alcohol or coffee...

Comment: @DarthLocke I thought about that. I also thought about it as an oversight of production or with lack of branding, it being vague to imply the above.

Comment: @blankip it does! But this was released in 1991, and Zima became available in 1993. Of importance, this beverage is carbonated and you can hear the sound of opening with carbonation releasing. This could be seltzer water, possibly Crystal Pepsi, but none of that explains the stirring afterward. I do think @ DarthLocke has a point where they were trying to look cool -- thus leaving the viewer to imply this is indeed alcohol.